# Ajax redirect after create or not?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using Ajax in a form successfully, but I cannot find out whats the best way to do after a create action?

I am using respond_with and to use the same logic in an Ajax call the create.js file should render a partial show when everything is OK and a partial new with error data when something goes wrong.
However in same cases the show and new actions are rather complex and defines a set of variables used in the partials. This means that I have to repeat the code that defines the variables in the create action in order to be able to display the partials from the create.js file.

That seems not to be good practice and I suspect that am not using Ajax correctly. 
I have learned that one should not try to redirect after an Ajax call, but I have not found any example of create.js file that solves my problem

Is it good practice to do as I am doing or are there better ways to handle the output from the create action using
 Ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand you, you want render all the form "new" if there was errors.

You shouldn't do that, cause new form already is on the screen (with data that user typed). You could render only errors block in ajax response.

Comment: OK that solves that problem - could mI use the error helper from rails to do that.

Comment: How about the other problem. Should I render the show partial

Comment: You may create 2 js.erb files - create.js.erb and errors.js.erb.

In first place smth like that:
$('#show').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'show_new')) %>');

In second:
$('#error_explanation').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'error_messages')) %>');

Of course, replace names of partials and DOM ids by your names. But logic can be that.